# What does "Debugging, Restart" mean in Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

My server was debugging. When I changed some code, the Tomcat server's status went to "Debugging, Restart". I found that the code was reflected without restarting (due to hot swap). What does "Debugging, Restart" means? Does it mean that a restart is required?